# Selecionar 5 mil linhas de uma tabela

Tags: select

Tenho uma tabela com mais de 5 mil linhas, onde tenho uma coluna com ano, nomes_municipios e outra com valores. Eu consigo tirar uma média com um municipio que está representado em uma linha, mas eu queria fazer com todos de uma vez só. São todos os municípios brasileiros. Existe alguma forma?
Este é o código que estou usando, mas com esse código, só consigo fazer pra um de cada vez.

```
SELECT nome, AVG(cota_fpm)
FROM economia
where nome = 'Alta Floresta D''Oeste';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta agrupar o resultado pelos nomes dos municípios utilizando o **group by**.

Tenta com esta *query*:

```
SELECT nome, AVG(cota_fpm)
FROM economia
GROUP BY nome;
```

Comment: Vou tentar e já posto o resultado.

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado. Deu tudo certinho aqui.